# Selenium - WebDriver not working with profile options

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I was trying to run my code after a few months. It worked fine back then when I wrote but now -after some version updates- it keeps giving errors. Without those option arguments, it works fine.

Here it is simplified;

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)        
browser.get("https://google.com")

browser.quit()
```

It said **Devtoolsactiveport file doesn't exist** then I solved version conflicting errors and after tried adding `--headless` and this helped a little but somewhere ahead it crashed again.

Now I added `options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=5040")` and it says **Chrome not reachable** this time.
`--disable-dev-shm-usage` and `--no-sandbox` options did'nt help also.

Comment: Chromedriver 109? One of the Selenium maintainers (Titus) just filed a Chromedriver bug about that: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4328 (Possibly related to your issue)

Comment: @СергейКох Well **this code keeps giving error** means it doesn't work well and i need to fix error which appeared. It's clear and I got what i need. Thanks anyway